# Square taper bottom bracket noise from street riding fixed gear

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, fixed-gear, noise

I’ve been trying to eliminate crank/bb noise  in several different Sugino RD2 cranksets over the years with no luck. Always a faint click, once per revolution on the crankarms.

I’ve tightened EVERYTHING. I’ve tried grease and locktite in different ways on crank bolts and chainring bolts. The mechanics all say everything looks good. I’ve had BB shells faced. I’ve installed the BBs myself, and had shops do it. Always tons of grease. I’ve done this with several frames, and many different pedals.

I’ve heard some say you have to tighten the crank bolts, ride, tighten, ride, tighten, ride, tighten, etc... And I have done that too.

Still a click. I’ve had several of these sets. New. All the same problem.

My understanding is that it’s more difficult to get the system quiet because of reversal of torque from riding and skidding involved in street riding fixed, vs on the track where there’s not much reason to skid in the velodrome.

But I haven’t tried non-Sugino cranksets or bottom brackets.

Is this a common problem to do with all square taper fixed gear street riders, or just Sugino systems?

I have a hard time believing Sugino would continually make a noisy product.

I’ve had several different non-square-taper systems, and they are always quiet. It makes me think square tapers are just bad for street riding fixed.

Comment: A description of the noise would help

Comment: It’s a faint click.

Comment: If everything else has been checked, it's probably the bottom bracket. Track components don't always do well in dirty and wet conditions, so I'd replace the bottom bracket with MTB one. Anything with correct length and thread and JIS taper should work. There are many options, in my experience Shimano BB-UN55 works well, is cheap and available in all possible configurations.

Comment: Hm, k. I have a non-sugino bb on hand. Maybe I’ll try that before I give up. Will have to wait until the snow melts, haha. They’re 103mm spindle for these, so not a whole lot of options.

Comment: There are plenty of non-sugino brands out there, and most of them are junk. I'd really recommend buying a quality BB, since they are ridiculously cheap compared to any other component.

Comment: Imo square taper is not any better/worse than other types of BB for street riding. I've ridden many many bikes with square taper through rain/mud etc. with no problems (until they become very worn). Perhaps your sugino BB has worse seals since it's meant for track usage.. which would cause water/grid etc to be able to enter more easily causing premature wear/more noise. When did the noise start? was it already present when the BB was new?

Comment: @Maarten yes. Noisy from the start.

Comment: Do you hear the click when standing to pedal? You can get exactly the same kind of once per pedal rotation clicking from saddle rails/ seatpost clamp. If it's the saddle/seatpost, it goes away when you stand to pedal.

Comment: Another place to look is for any small cracks in the frame.

Comment: Does your BB use sealed/cartridge bearings or (caged) ball bearings?

Comment: Noise can originate from the bearings, from caged bearings or a cartridge shifting, from the crank arms, or from the pedals.  You can also get a click from a loose chainring, or from the chain "catching" on the chainring as it comes on or off.

Comment: Oh, and then there's the case where one of the crank arms scrapes the chain stay.  Plus cracks in the frame, etc.

Comment: Or the noise can come from somewhere else. I’ve had clicks from a pedal that needed servicing, a rim where the joining sleeve was loose, the crank hitting my FD cable, and probably others. QR skewers are one place to look as well.

Comment: Strange problem. This is a common crank so I don't think they all do this. You don't mention shoes and I've definitely seen shoes do things like this - have you eliminated that by ridden in two totally different shoe/pedal combos? Is chainline measuring good with a tool, not just on paper? No slightly dinged tooth on a ring that might have been going for a while? Riding with a chain that's at a wear life appropriate for the ring, and does it do it at different levels of chain tension?

Comment: a bent tooth on front chainring or possible on rear sprocket (less likely) can also cause such a click (once per rotation) by lifting the chain up and then when the tension gets too high the chain 'falls' off the bent tooth making the a fore mentioned noise.

Comment: have you removed the cranks and felt how smooth the axle rotates? does the axle rotate smoothly for the full 360 degrees?